# Visual Studio "Project reference" references to lower version of package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, xunit, npgsql

Have two projects, lets assume "Project" & "Project.Tests" (xUnit project)

Build fails after adding "Project" as a project reference to "Project.Tests" by the following error

[image]

It becomes little bit strange after looking to the dependencies

"Project" dependencies:

[image]

"Project.Tests" dependencies:

[image]

Both projects have the same dotnet core version

[image]

The question is, why does such a thing happen if i'm referencing to a project (not manually install a package with specific version)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I figured out the problem.

"Project" has a nuget package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" of version 3.1.7(which causes problem), after downgrading it to the version 3.1.4 problem was resolved.